# Storing non-state variables in functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Below are two React Components that do *almost* the same thing. One is a function; the other is a class. Each Component has an `Animated.Value` with an async listener that updates `_foo` on change. I need to be able to access `_foo` in the functional component like I do with `this._foo` in the classical component.

- `FunctionalBar` should not have `_foo` in the global scope in case there are more than one `FunctionalBar`.
- `FunctionalBar` cannot have `_foo` in the function scope because `_foo` is reinitialized every time the `FunctionalBar` renders. `_foo` also should not be in state because the component does not need to render when `_foo` changes.
- `ClassBar` does not have this problem because it keeps `_foo` initialized on `this` throughout the entire life of the Component.

How do I keep `_foo` initialized throughout the life of `FunctionalBar` without putting it in the global scope?

#### Functional Implementation

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, View } from 'react-native';

var _foo = 0;

function FunctionalBar(props) {

  const foo = new Animated.Value(0);

  _onChangeFoo({ value }) {
    _foo = value;
  }

  function showFoo() {
    let anim = Animated.timing(foo, { toValue: 1, duration: 1000, useNativeDriver: true });
    anim.start(() => console.log(_foo));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    foo.addListener(_onChangeFoo);
    showFoo();
    return () => foo.removeListener(_onChangeFoo);   
  });

  return <View />;

}
```

#### Classical Implementation

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, View } from 'react-native';

class ClassBar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { foo: new Animated.Value(0) };
    this._foo = 0;
    this._onChangeFoo = this._onChangeFoo.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.foo.addListener(this._onChangeFoo);
    this.showFoo();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.foo.removeListener(this._onChangeFoo);
  }

  showFoo() {
    let anim = Animated.timing(this.state.foo, { toValue: 1, duration: 1000, useNativeDriver: true });
    anim.start(() => console.log(this._foo));
  }

  _onChangeFoo({ value }) {
    this._foo = value;
  }

  render() {
    return <View />;
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `const foo = useState(new Animated.Value(0));`?

Comment: That doesn't address the problem because I still need to attach the listener. This is a scope question.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are trying to achieve. Sure, logging something on the instance obviously won't work in a function component, but what do you want to do with `_foo`?

Comment: Make an imperative call in a `useEffect`.

Comment: I could have a global object with all every `_foo` and clean it up on unmount. It feels like there needs to be another hook (or a scope passed to `useEffect`).

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) hook is not just for DOM refs, but can store any mutable value you like.

**Example**

```
function FunctionalBar(props) {
  const [foo] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
  const _foo = useRef(0);

  function showFoo() {
    let anim = Animated.timing(foo, { toValue: 1, duration: 1000, useNativeDriver: true });
    anim.start(() => console.log(_foo.current));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    function _onChangeFoo({ value }) {
      _foo.current = value;
    }

    foo.addListener(_onChangeFoo);
    showFoo();
    return () => foo.removeListener(_onChangeFoo);
  }, []);

  return <View />;
}
```

Comment: Why does it work this way? In non-React functions, you can directly set _foo (provided you change it from `const` to `let`) inside a function so long as it is still in scope. What's happening here that makes this different?

Comment: useRef returns an object whose reference would not change across re-renders, the actual value for foo is then kept in the current property of that object. @Scribblemacher

Answer (score 24):

You can use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) hook (it's the recommended way stated in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables)):

- Declaring variable: `const a = useRef(5) // 5 is initial value`
- getting the value: `a.current`
- setting the value: `a.current = my_value`

Comment: This closed a huge hole in my understanding of functional components. Thx. I have switched to class components a number of times just because I didn't know this existed.

Answer (score 12):

Just to support Tholle answer here is the official documentation

[Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

> However, `useRef()` is useful for more than the ref attribute. It’s
> handy for keeping any mutable value around similar to how you’d use
> instance fields in classes.
>
> This works because `useRef()` creates a plain JavaScript object. The
> only difference between `useRef()` and creating a `{current: ...}` object
> yourself is that `useRef` will give you the same ref object on every
> render.
>
> Keep in mind that `useRef` doesn’t notify you when its content changes.
> Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render. If you want
> to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node,
> you may want to use a callback ref instead.

Answer (score 6):

I've had some luck using the [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) hook with destructuring (+ an optional variable alias "my"), and then you keep all your values in the `my` object so you don't have to use multiple refs or keep using `myref.current` all the time:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const componentRef = useRef({});
  const { current: my } = componentRef;

  my.count = 42;
  console.log(my.count); // 42

  my.greet = "hello";
  console.log(my.greet); // hello

  return <div />;
}
```

Comment: So clever, I really like this. Do you follow any other similar practices when refactoring a class component to RFC?

Comment: a nice way to not repeating `.current` everytimes you read ref value.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty unusual example, but if I'm reading this correctly, you simply want to store unique `_foo` objects everytime the component mounts and destroy them when it unmounts, but also prevent extra rerenders when this value changes.

I have run into this scenario before and simple object (map / hash) should do the trick:

```
let foos = {}
let fooCount = 0

function F(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    let fooId = fooCount++
    foos[fooId] = new Animated.Value(0)
    foos[fooId].addListener(...)
    return () => foos[fooId].removeListener(...)
  }, []) // <-- do not rerun when called again (only when unmounted)

  ...render...
}
```

or something to that effect. if you have a runnable example could tweak it to make it fit your example better. either way, most things with scope problems are solved with primitives.

Comment: what is the difference between decraling `foos` outside of function F, vs inside?

Comment: @vikrant component functions are called everytime something renders, so if you put normal variable declarations inside then they get overwritten on every render.

Comment: This will be fine if you only have 1 instance of the component on the page at any one time. But if you have multiple components the variables declared outside the component function will be used for all the components. I've found it's best to use the useRef method.