# Avoid TextInput re render on text change

Tags: react-native

I have a simple TextInput and a submit button and I want to handle text change without re render the componenent. On a class component I use a private variable "textContent" triggering OnChangeText event instead of a state to prevent forced rendering but I don't know how to do that with function component. Is it possible to store the text value without state on function component ? Thanks

Here is the component (that re render on text change) :

```
const Search = () => {
    const [_films, setFilms] = useState([]);
    const [_text, setText] = useState('');

    const _loadFilms = () => {
        console.log(_text);
        if (_text.length > 0) {
            getFilmsFromApiWithSearchedText(_text).then(data => {
                setFilms(data.results);
            });
        }
    }
    
    console.log("rendering");

    return (
        <View style={styles.main_container}>
            <TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder='Titre du film' onChangeText={(text) => setText(text)} />
            <Button title='Rechercher' onPress={() => { _loadFilms() }} />
            <FlatList
                data={_films}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <FilmItem film={item} />}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    main_container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 20
    },
    textinput: {
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        height: 50,
        borderColor: '#000000',
        borderWidth: 1,
        paddingLeft: 5
    }
});

export default Search;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a class component you could store the text in a private variable of the class. With functional components you can use refs for something equivalent. More info about how, available in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53146575/storing-non-state-variables-in-functional-components) SO question